# Combining/concatenating more than two expressionsets in R

Tags: r, set, expression, concatenation

I do have several Expressionsets (Eset) that I would like to combine together.
I found a package to combine two Esets but I have around 10 Esets which I want to combine.
here is the package that combines two Esets with the example:

```
library('a4Base')

## Not run: 
# prepare and combine two ExpressionSet

data(data.H2009); data(phenoData.H2009)
data(data.SKOV3); data(phenoData.SKOV3)

eH2009 <- prepareExpressionSet(exprs = data.H2009, phenoData = phenoData.H2009, changeColumnsNames = TRUE)
eSKOV3  <- prepareExpressionSet(exprs = data.SKOV3, phenoData = phenoData.SKOV3, changeColumnsNames = TRUE)

newE <- combineTwoExpressionSet(eH2009,eSKOV3)

## End(Not run)
```

Is there any way that I could combine them all at once?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I do not know this package nor the amount of data you're using, but just in case, try do.call(combineTwoExpressionSet, yourListOfEsets)

Comment: I did it but because combineTwoExpressionSet is only used for two Esets, I got this error:

Error in (function (x, y)  : 
  unused argument (<S4 object of class "ExpressionSet">)

Comment: have you properly put your Esets in a list before, like Elist <- list(Eset1,Eset2,Eset3) then do.call(combineTwoExpressionSet, Elist) ?

Comment: Ask questions about Bioconductor packages on the [Bioconductor support site](https://support.bioconductor.org).

Comment: I've finally found the solution.
There is a package called InsilicoMerging. I post the answer in case some one also has the problem as mine. Take a look at this:
[InSilicoMerging](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/inSilicoMerging.html)